# Por que as strings (QString) não aparecem durante a depuração no Visual Studio?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2015, debug

Tenho um programa em [Qt](http://www.qt.io/) 5 em que utilizo `QString` para manipular strings de texto. Porém, quando vou depurar o programa, não consigo enxergar o conteúdo das strings (seja na janela "Auto", "Locals" ou "Watch", ou mesmo quando deixo o ponteiro do mouse sobre a variável. O depurador do Visual Studio (eu uso a versão 2015) exibe o conteúdo em memória do objeto `QString` ao invés do texto diretamente (como fazia em versões anteriores do Qt ou do VS):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como eu faço para que o depurador exiba corretamente o texto da string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse é o comportamento padrão do Visual Studio em qualquer versão. Uma vez que ele não sabe como apresentar o objeto `QString`, ele apresenta seu conteúdo interno da melhor forma que pode.

O que ocorre é que quando se instala o [Qt Visual Studio Add-in](http://doc.qt.io/vs-addin/), ele instala um visualizador customizado no seu VS permitindo que as `QStrings` sejam facilmente enxergadas em tempo de depuração.

Se por algum motivo você não puder instalar o Qt VS Add-in (se o seu VS for a versão *Express*, por exemplo), você pode instalar o visualizador manualmente. Faça assim:

1. Vá até o [repositório do Add-in no Github](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-labs-vstools), procure e baixe o arquivo com extensão `.natvis` da versão do Qt que utiliza. Por exemplo, [este é o arquivo da versão 5](https://github.com/qtproject/qt-labs-vstools/blob/master/tools/Qt4EEAddin/qt5.natvis) do Qt.
2. Copie esse arquivo para a pasta `<MyDocuments>\Visual Studio <versão>\Visualizers`. No caso do Visual Studio 2015 que eu tenho aqui, por exemplo, é a pasta `C:\Users\Luiz\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Visualizers`. Ela provavelmente já existe, mas se não existir pode criá-la.
3. Reinicie o Visual Studio.

Depois de reiniciar, as strings utilizando `QString` serão facilmente enxergadas no depurador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Note que o arquivo `.natvis` também contém visualizadores para outros objetos do Qt. Ele é grande demais para reproduzir completamente aqui, mas apenas para referência, ele tem esse formato na versão 5:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AutoVisualizer xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/debugger/natvis/2010">

    <Type Name="QPoint">
        <AlternativeType Name="QPointF"/>
        <DisplayString>{{ x = {xp}, y = {yp} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[x]">xp</Item>
            <Item Name="[y]">yp</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>

    <Type Name="QRect">
        <DisplayString>{{ x = {x1}, y = {y1}, width = {x2 - x1 + 1}, height = {y2 - y1 + 1} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[x]">x1</Item>
            <Item Name="[y]">y1</Item>
            <Item Name="[width]">x2 - x1 + 1</Item>
            <Item Name="[height]">y2 - y1 + 1</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>

    <Type Name="QSize">
        <AlternativeType Name="QSizeF"/>
        <DisplayString>{{ width = {wd}, height = {ht} }}</DisplayString>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[width]">wd</Item>
            <Item Name="[height]">ht</Item>
        </Expand>
    </Type>

    . . .

    <Type Name="QString">
        <DisplayString>{((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),sub}</DisplayString>
        <StringView>((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),sub</StringView>
        <Expand>
            <Item Name="[size]">d-&gt;size</Item>
            <Item Name="[referenced]">d-&gt;ref.atomic._q_value</Item>
            <ArrayItems>
                <Size>d-&gt;size</Size>
                <ValuePointer>((reinterpret_cast&lt;unsigned short*&gt;(d)) + d->offset / 2),c</ValuePointer>
            </ArrayItems>
        </Expand>
    </Type>

    . . .

</AutoVisualizer>
```

Para saber mais sobre os visualizadores nativos do Visual Studio, consulte [a documentação](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620914.aspx).